# Running predictive model according to values in column

Tags: r, dataframe, prediction

I have a dataframe (I might in future not use it):

```
> PM
  names.model.
1            4
2            5
3            6
4            8
5            9
```

It means that for value of `4` for instance I'll use `model[1]`, for value of `5` I'll use `model[2]` etc.
As already mentioned I have a list of model (from 1 to 5). 
I have another dataframe, that has a column `TN`. 
As can be seen:

```
> head (test)
   Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day TN
2     36     118  8.0   72     5   2  4
8     19      99 13.8   59     5   8  4
14    14     274 10.9   68     5  14  5
40    71     291 13.8   90     6   9  9
62   135     269  4.1   84     7   1  8
69    97     267  6.3   92     7   8  9
```

I would like to run the add a new column `test$Ozone_pred` that will run the relevant model per line. For instance, for the first line I'll run `model[1]` as well as for the second line (both are 4). For the third line I'll run `model[2]` , for the forth line `model[5]` etc.

Comment: Hard to replicate your data like that.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple options. First would be to use dplyr's join function to just add your first dataframe (PM) to the second one (test) as a new column and then index based on that. Below is a solution with base R.

To get the correct function for a single row as your current PM is:

```
model[match(test_TN_number, PM[,2])]
```

If PM doesn't have the first column equal to row numbers, then:

```
model[PM[match(test_TN_number, PM[,2])],1]
```

This is then easily extended to the whole dataframe with apply or within a loop.

Edit: here's a for looped version:

```
for (test_TN_number in test[,"TN"]){
  model[PM[match(test_TN_number, PM[,2])],1]
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Aaro Viertiö, Can you add the apply for the whole dataframe (or loop).

Comment: Added a looped version.